# Inheriting from a custom UIViewController class and displaying two UIViewController classes components?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a UIViewController class SurveyPanel that inherits from UIViewController like so

```
SurveyPanel : UIViewController
```

Then I have another UIViewController class called AnnouncementPanel that inherits from SurveyPanel

```
AnnouncementPanel : SurveyPanel
```

I need AnnouncementPanel to display both buttons from SurveyPanel and buttons specific to AnnouncementPanel, but currently it will only display components within SurveyPanel.
Could it be the way I load the controllers in my AppDelegate.cs?
Currently I'm doing:

```
window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreenBounds);
AnnouncementPanel viewController = new AnnouncementPanel();
window.RootViewController = viewController;
window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you create UI in views by loading XIB files or by code?

If "by loading XIB files", it's a bit messy to use prepared UI with UIViewController inheritance.

If "by code", please double check that you:

1. Create controls, which are belong to AnnouncementPanel;
2. Call AddSubview to add controls to AnnouncementPanel.View;
3. Set up controls frames correctly (in visible part of screen);
4. Call base (i.e. SurveyPanel) controls creation.

Example, which I use for inheritance of (UITableViewCells) views:

```
// Base cell
public class UserCell: UIViewController
{

    string cellId = "CustomCell2";
    UITableViewCell cell;
    public UITableViewCell Cell {
        get { 
            if (cell == null)
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId);
            return cell; }
    }

    protected UIImageViewAvatar IvaAvatar;
    protected UILabel LblPerson;

    ...

    public UserCell (string cellId)
    {
        this.cellId = cellId;

        IvaAvatar = new UIImageViewAvatar ();
        LblPerson = new UILabel ();

        Cell.AddSubview (IvaAvatar);
        Cell.AddSubview (LblPerson);
    }

    ...

}

// Inherited cell
public class MessageCell: UserCell
{
    protected UILabel LblText;
    protected UILabel LblDatePlace;

    Message message;
    public Message Message {
        get { return message; } 
        set {
            message = value;
            Render ();
        }
    }

    ...

    // 4.
    // It is important to call base constructor
    public MessageCell (string cellId): base(cellId)
    {
        // 1.
        LblText = new UILabel ();
        LblDatePlace = new UILabel ();

        // 2.
        // Adding more controls to (Cell) View
        Cell.AddSubview (LblText);
        Cell.AddSubview (LblDatePlace);
    }

    ...

    // 3.
            // Render is called when someone set up Message property
    // So frames will be changed according to new data
    public new void Render()
    {
        base.Render();

        // Text
        LblText.Text = Message.Text;
        LblText.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (Constants.FONT_SIZE_MESSAGE);

        LblText.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        LblText.Lines = 0;
        LblText.Frame = new RectangleF (LblPerson.Frame.Left, LblPerson.Frame.Bottom //+ Constants.SIZE_IDENT*/
                                        ,
                                        Cell.Frame.Width - LblPerson.Frame.Left - Constants.SIZE_IDENT, 0);
        LblText.SizeToFit ();

    }
}
```

Comment: I just edit the .xib files and let Mono do the code, no matter what I seem to change the parent UIViewController components always seem to show up over the UIViewController that inherits it.

Comment: @Smoore, yes, sir. Seems like you declare AnnouncementPanel constructor as "public AnnouncementPanel () {}" by remove calling base constructor ": base ("AnnouncementPanel", null)" cause base class SurveyPanel doesnt't have such type constructor. In that way YES,  AnnouncementPanel don't loads it's UI from XIB-file, thus you will never see controls from AnnouncementPanel.xib. Please provide AnnouncementPanel and SurveyPanel constructors for reference.
I recommend you to create these views UI completely by code like on example below.

Comment: That's correct, I removed the ": base ("AnnouncementPanel", null)" from the constructor due to errors. Here are the constructors currently from both of them 
    public SurveyPanel () : base ("SurveyPanel", null) { this.Title = "Survey"; } public AnnouncementPanel() { this.Title = "Announcement"; }

Comment: Since AnnouncementPanel doesn't call base constructor with "AnnouncementPanel" xib-file parameter, it doesn't load XIB-file with UI.

Comment: Is there a way I can get it to call said constructor without an error so that it loads the xib-file with the UI?

Comment: You could fix AnnouncementPanel constructor, which will load AnnouncementPanel.xib interface (and I will help you if you need it so). But, unfortunately, I believe that it is impossible to load 2 XIB-files and mix their contents. Try to create AnnouncementPanel view content on it's ViewDidLoad event by code i.e. after base view loaded.